# Get a random row from a MySQL table with no primary key - optimized

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

So here's my mission: return a random row from a MySQL table with no primary key. A quick search returned [this page](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm) and this solution:

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

Unfortunately, the solution is not optimized, as [this site](http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/) makes clear. They propose the following fix, which is in PHP:

```
$offset_result = mysql_query( " SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM `table` ");
$offset_row = mysql_fetch_object( $offset_result );
$offset = $offset_row->offset;
$result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT $offset, 1 " );
```

Good enough as I'll be publishing this on a page, but in the meantime I need to try it in raw MySQL. So I punched in:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
LIMIT (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) FROM `table`), 1;
```

... and got the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) FROM `table`), 1' at line 3
```

But I don't understand, because the individual components work perfectly. If I enter:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) 
FROM `table`
```

... I get a random number from 0 up to the number of rows minus 1. Likewise, if I enter:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
LIMIT 2, 1
```

... I get the third row in the table (or the fourth row if I substitute 3 for 2, etc.)

What am I doing wrong?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html -  LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements). This suggests you could read `Floor(rand() * count(*))` into a variable and then use it to pick the random row.

Comment: `mysql_query( " SELECT " . FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) . " AS `offset` FROM `table` ")`

Comment: You could use a stored procedure to save the value of the RAND() * COUNT but you might be better off saving the total of the rows in your web app, depending on how often it's updated. Also, depending on how many rows you are talking about, the original non-optimized solution may be fast enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a random sample, the following may be fast enough:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table` t cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from table t) const
WHERE rand() <= 100 / cnt
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1 ;
```

This does have to scan the table, but the sort is on roughly 100 rows, which should be fast enough.